# How to extend urllib3 connection creation to add additional authentication step?

Tags: cloudant, urllib3

I would like to create a connection pool to a https endpoint where an addition step is performed after creating each https connection in the pool. The step is to make a [https call](https://docs.cloudant.com/authentication.html) like so:

```
POST /_session HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*

name=YourUserName&password=YourPassword
```

If successful, in response a cookie is returned, e.g:

```
200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 14:06:11 GMT
server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
Set-Cookie: AuthSession="a2ltc3RlYmVsOjUxMzRBQTUzOtiY2_IDUIdsTJEVNEjObAbyhrgz"; Expires=Tue, 05 Mar 2013 14:06:11 GMT; Max-Age=86400; Path=/; HttpOnly; Version=1
x-couch-request-id: a638431d
```

Where would this extra step go?  For example, maybe I should extend the [_new_conn](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/1.20/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L812) method?

```
class CustomHTTPSConnectionPool(HTTPSConnectionPool):

    def _new_conn(self):
        conn = super(CustomHTTPSConnectionPool, self)._new_conn()
        ... call '/_session' and save cookie
        return conn
```

Another consideration is that the cookie will expire and should be renewed, ideally before the expiration.  I'm just noting it here, that should probably be the subject of a separate question.

Comment: If you're trying to create your own CustomHTTPSConnectionPool, you're on the right track. But reading the docs you linked, I don't think you need this? It seems the state is maintained in the cookie rather than the connection, so you just need to do the handshake, get a cookie, and make sure you pass the cookie with each request and you're good to go regardless of connections?

Comment: Ah, yes.  That makes a lot of sense - thanks!  If you wanted to convert this to an answer, I can +1 it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As discussed in the comments)

If you're trying to create your own CustomHTTPSConnectionPool, you're on the right track.

But reading the docs you linked, I don't think you need this? It seems the state is maintained in the cookie rather than the connection, so you just need to do the handshake, get a cookie, and make sure you pass the cookie with each request and you're good to go regardless of connections.